# MATLAB: Nested for-loop takes longer every successive iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

**/edit: The loop doesn't become slower. I didn't take the time correctly. See Rasman's answer.**

I'm looping over 3 parameters for a somewhat long and complicated function and I noticed two things that I don't understand:

1. The execution gets slower with each successive iteration, although the function only returns one struct (of which I only need one field) that I overwrite with each iteration.
2. The profiler shows that the `end` statement for the innermost `for` takes a quite long time.

Consider the following example (I'm aware that this can easily be vectorized, but as far as I understand the function I call can't):

```
function stuff = doSomething( x, y, z )
    stuff.one = x+y+z;
    stuff.two = x-y-z;
end
```

and how I execute the function

```
n = 50;
i = 0;
currenttoc = 0;
output = zeros(n^3,4);
tic
for x = 1:n
    for y = 1:n
        for z = 1:n
            i = i + 1;
            output(i,1) = x;
            output(i,2) = y;
            output(i,3) = z;
            stuff = doSomething(x,y,z);
            output(i,4) = stuff.one;
            if mod(i,1e4) == 0 % only for demonstration, not in final script
                currenttoc = toc - currenttoc;
                fprintf(1,'time for last 10000 iterations: %f \n',currenttoc)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How can I speed this up? Why does every iteration take longer than the one before? I'm pretty sure this is horrible programming, sorry for that.

Comment: If i am understanding correctly, try to set up the first three columns first, then write your doSomething function in vector format. Eg- 1) populate the first three columns with 1,1,1-50;1,2,1-50;etc.., then have doSomething return a vector of values that you will use as stuff's final column because those additions and subtractions are simple vector operations as well.

Comment: I can populate the first three columns outside of the loop, that is true. Thanks for that. This isn't really slow, though. What I cannot do is vectorize `doSomething` - it's only that simple in my example, in reality, it is a quite complicated function (with a handful of subfunctions). Do you know why, although `doSomething` always does the same and `stuff` is overwritten every iteration, the loop slows down very quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem gets largely eliminated when I replace the if statement with:

```
if mod(i,1e4) == 0 % only for demonstration, not in final script
    fprintf(1,'time for last 10000 iterations: %f \n',toc); tic;
end
```

I think the operation on toc may be causing the problem

Comment: You are correct. My code snippet to take the time didn't really make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When I replace the call to `doSomething` with `output(i,4)=toc;`, and I plot `diff(output(:,4))`, I see that it's the call to `fprintf` that takes longer and longer every time, apparently.

Removing the `if-clause` returns to every iteration taking about the same amount of time.

Comment: aha, excellent catch - storing the printfs into a memory buffer and then writing to file all at once may be an optimization?

Comment: @AK4749: that's always a good option, since `fprintf` tends to be slow.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. I removed the `fprintf` in my actual code and implemented your solution (storing `toc` in `output`). Before, I used `disp()` for output of iteration times. Without any text output to the command window `plot(diff(output(:,4)))` looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/VPYRWP8.png - would you say that looks like we eliminated the bottleneck? :)

Comment: Eh, for some reason even with the `fprintf`-statement the plot looks quite similar. Makes me wonder why the `currenttoc` stuff in my question says 100 iterations take longer every single time it prints?! /edit: ... it does because I didn't programm it correctly. Thanks to all of you. I think I've seen a problem where there was none. Rasman shows how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's MUCH faster if `doSomething` returns multiple output variables rather than a struct

```
function [out1,out2] = doSomething( x, y, z )
    out1 = x+y+z;
    out2 = x-y-z;
end
```

The fact that it gets slower on each subsequent iteration is strange and i have no explanation for it but hopefully that gives you some speed up at least.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change that. The function is used in a few other scripts and works with structs pretty much everywhere (because there's lots of variables returned). I will keep that in mind for future programming, though, so thanks for the advice!